# Обновление проводника в режиме "Запускать окна с папками в отдельном процессе"

Tags: обновление, explorer

У меня есть расширение Shell (Shell Extention), которое для определённых файлов меняет иконку в Проводнике(Explorer). В обычном режиме всё работает нормально и после смены иконки файла достаточно просто обновить проводник (F5), чтобы изменения стали видны. Но если в Проводнике установлена опция "Запускать окна с папками в отдельном процессе" (как показано тут https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/125919-enable-disable-launch-folder-windows-separate-process-windows.html), то изменения становятся видными только после перезапуска проводника. Обычное обновление не помогает.
В чем причина такого поведения и можно ли как-то на него повлиять?